# Batch file alteration

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Morning All.
I currently run the following code in a batch file that lists and deletes items in a specific location. It outputs the path and file names to a file that is then emailed to me so i can store an updated version for auditing reasons.

```
forfiles -p "D:\Data\Folder1" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c echo %DATE% - %TIME% = @path" >> "C:\Deleted Files.txt"**

forfiles -p "D:\Data\Folder1" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del /Q @file"
```

There are then 3 entries in the batch file which work for the other folders as required.

I now have to alter the code and create a new file for a different location which will look like this:

- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company1\Foldera
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company1\Folderb
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company1\Folderc
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company2\Foldera
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company2\Folderb
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company2\Folderc
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company3\Foldera
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company3\Folderb
- D:\Data\SalesArea\Company3\Folderc

I need to be able to search specific sub folder for each company and empty said folder. For example Folderb is the only one that requires cleaning. And it needs to check Folderb for each company. With the possibility of companies being added or removed inbetween it being run each week.

I'm guessing the code needs some type of loop/if logic adding to it however I'm not profficient enough to know what or how to change it.

Any assistance greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution will be to use `findstr` to find the directorys.
But this solution shoul be used very carrefully if in your pathes you have the searched name It will match it and delete it's files  too.

You can test it and see the output (I putted an echo before the `DEL`) if the output is correct and only the concerned folder are displayed then you can use it (removing the `ECHO`).

```
@echo off

set "$startingDir=D:\Data\SalesArea"
set /p "$dir=Enter the name of the dir to clean : "

pushd "%$StartingDir%"
for /d /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a | findstr /i "%$dir%" >nul && echo del "%%a\*.*"
popd
```